# Filemaker go connection to FM database

Tags: ios, iphone, filemaker

Is it possible to connect FM go on my iPhone to the FM pro database on the server when the iPhone is not on the same network?

The server has a firewall and remote access is actually only possible though a VPN tunnel.

If not, what opportunities do I have to have a remote acces to the database without copying the file onto the smartphone, and to update the db as soon the iPhone is back in the same WLAN? Due to a slow VPN, installing the VPN on the smartphone is an undesirable option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to open a specific port in the firewall (5003) and redirect to the FileMaker Server.

You can also try to remote on one of the local computers from the phone if it is allowed by firewall, but I think you will find using it a bit awkward.

The best option is to use VPN (which you don't want to), so may be it is worth investigating why it is slow. Is it generally slow or it is slow with FIleMaker only? You might have to optimise your system.

Comment: thank you for your input. VPN was set up by an IT company. It's always slow. Due to narrow resources, it won't be possible to change the whole VPN thing :-( First option seems to be most useful for us, I will try this!

Comment: You will need to look at port forwarding: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9770/~/port-forwarding-information and http://hbase.net/2013/03/13/filemaker-how-to-setup-a-network-router-for-filemaker-remote-access/